# How to build a sliding menu in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my current code but im trying to achieve a hover effect like the one on
http://www.fullyillustrated.com

where it has the blue glow thing that hovers over what ever page you mouse on and when you take the mouse of it goes back to whatever page you are on

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> Hover </li>
    <li>Me </li>
  </ul>
</nav>​
```

CSS CODE

```
body {
   padding: 50px;
}

li {
   float: left;
   padding: 20px;
   background: #ddd;
   cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
   background: #999;
}
```

Comment: They actually have a separate span with `background: url("http://www.fullyillustrated.com/wp-content/themes/fullyIllustrated/_include/img/background-highlight.png") transparent;` which they move around

Comment: I have tried using an image for the effect, but it doesn't work when you mouse off the nav item,

Comment: @Bergi That seems to only be for the highlighting of the text, not the underline. Unless I'm mistaken, I'll look again...

Comment: @Bergi And that isn't the actual URL. I think you meant `background-navigation.gif`?

Comment: @Ian: No, [it is](http://www.fullyillustrated.com/wp-content/themes/fullyIllustrated/_include/img/background-highlight.png) the underline - the background of the `#higlight` span

Comment: @Bergi Ahh I see, the thing I pointed out is for the highlighting of the text (not the same URL you meant) and you pointed out the underline that I didn't realize.

Comment: This can be done without JavaScript/jQuery using pure CSS if you dont mind leaving out the UAs that dont support latest CSS.

Comment: @Ian: OK, I didn't realize that they used an image for the text (ouch, btw) and background...

Comment: @Jawad: Really, how? Sounds like a complicated job to move the glow.

Comment: @Bergi Haha yeah, the `<a>` share the same background image but have a different position in it for its text...and then on hover, it changes that position as well to make it look highlighted. - no text, just an empty element

Comment: @Bergi: You know better than me mate. Sure it's complicated. More coding, testing and time/efforts plus that fact that it will not work in all UAs. Can be done with/without images. But you already know that. May take me 1 hour to do it, but may take you 10 minutes!

Comment: Here's a similar effect with CSS3 and a touch of javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/Mc5by/

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with JQuery, I think it's the best way to do it. I found this article, hopefully it will help you:http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Comment: no problem, that is why we are here, to help you searching and finding answers. Don't forget to mark the answer so everybody knows that this answer is answered.